# Package 'Win10SDK_10.0.15063.UWP,version=10.0.15063.19' failed to install

Tags: .net, visual-studio, xamarin, uwp

I am getting the following error when trying to modify Visual Studio 2017 components and install.

```
The product failed to install the listed workloads and components due to one or more package failures.

Incomplete workloads
    Mobile development with .NET (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCrossPlat,version=15.0.26403.0)
    Universal Windows Platform development (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Universal,version=15.0.26403.0)

Incomplete components
    Universal Windows Platform tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.UWP.Support,version=15.0.26412.1)
    Universal Windows Platform tools for Cordova (Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.UWP.Cordova,version=15.0.26403.0)
    Universal Windows Platform tools for Xamarin (Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.UWP.Xamarin,version=15.0.26403.0)
    Windows 10 SDK (10.0.15063.0) for UWP: C#, VB, JS (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.15063.UWP,version=15.0.26419.1)

You can search for solutions using the information below, modify your selections for the above workloads and components and retry the installation, or remove the product from your machine.

Following is a collection of individual package failures that led to the incomplete workloads and components above. To search for existing reports of these specific problems, please copy and paste the URL from each package failure into a web browser. If the issue has already been reported, you can find solutions or workarounds there. If the issue has not been reported, you can create a new issue where other people will be able to find solutions or workarounds.

Package 'Win10SDK_10.0.15063.UWP,version=10.0.15063.19' failed to install.
    Search URL: https://aka.ms/VSSetupErrorReports?q=PackageId=Win10SDK_10.0.15063.UWP;PackageAction=Install;ReturnCode=15605
    Impacted workloads
        Mobile development with .NET (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCrossPlat,version=15.0.26403.0)
        Universal Windows Platform development (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Universal,version=15.0.26403.0)
    Impacted components
        Universal Windows Platform tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.UWP.Support,version=15.0.26412.1)
        Universal Windows Platform tools for Cordova (Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.UWP.Cordova,version=15.0.26403.0)
        Universal Windows Platform tools for Xamarin (Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.UWP.Xamarin,version=15.0.26403.0)
        Windows 10 SDK (10.0.15063.0) for UWP: C#, VB, JS (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.15063.UWP,version=15.0.26419.1)
    Log
        C:\Users\kusal\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_setup_20170807105817_001_Win10SDK_10.0.15063.UWP.log
    Details
        Command executed: "c:\windows\syswow64\\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NonInteractive -NoLogo -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -InputFormat None "$ErrorActionPreference="""Stop"""; $VerbosePreference="""Continue"""; $ScriptPath="""C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\Win10SDK_10.0.15063.UWP,version=10.0.15063.19\WinSdkInstall.ps1"""; $SetupExe="""winsdksetup.exe"""; $SetupLogFolder="""windowssdk"""; $PackageId="""Win10SDK_10.0.15063.UWP"""; $LogFile="""C:\Users\kusal\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_setup_20170807105817_001_Win10SDK_10.0.15063.UWP.log"""; $SetupParameters="""/features OptionId.AvrfExternal OptionId.UWPManaged OptionId.WindowsSoftwareLogoToolkit OptionId.SigningTools OptionId.UWPLocalized /quiet /norestart"""; (gc $ScriptPath | out-string) | Invoke-Expression; if (!$?) { exit 1603 } elseif ($LastExitCode) { exit $LastExitCode }"
        Return code: 15605
        Return code details: There was a problem downloading your product.
```

The error log at C:\Users\kusal\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_setup_20170807105817_001_Win10SDK_10.0.15063.UWP.log :

```
Creating target folder C:\Users\kusal\AppData\Local\Temp\Win10SDK_10.0.15063.UWP_1205818002.
Launching 'winsdksetup.exe' with arguments '/features OptionId.AvrfExternal OptionId.UWPManaged OptionId.WindowsSoftwareLogoToolkit OptionId.SigningTools OptionId.UWPLocalized /quiet /norestart /Log "C:\Users\kusal\AppData\Local\Temp\windowssdk\dd_setup_20170807105817_001_Win10SDK_10.0.15063.UWP.winsdksetup.log"'.
Waiting for child process to terminate.
Child process terminated with exit code 15605.
Unknown exit code detected. Printing main log file:
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

(1) This happens when a downloaded installer file is corrupted or is giving an error during installation.

You can skip "Windows SDK" during the installation/modification and install the SDK separately. Download the SDK from 
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk

(2) Your antivirus guard or firewall can also be blocking the installation. Disable and check.

Comment: Can you please answer this one : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47723682/what-components-i-need-to-create-vs-2017-offline-layout-for-uwp-development